# How to replace a diagonal (not necessarily main diagonal) in a non-square matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

Say I have this matrix (call it `A`):

```
A = 
1 2 3 0   
1 2 3 4   
1 2 3 4   
0 2 3 4   
0 0 3 4
```

And this vector: `v = [5 6 7]`. I now want to replace the first diagonal above the main with this vector to obtain:

```
1 5 3 0   
1 2 6 4   
1 2 3 7   
0 2 3 4   
0 0 3 4
```

How do I do this in MATLAB for any size matrix and for any diagonal in that matrix?

Comment: Did you try `diag(v,k)` ?

Comment: @Dev-iL You should develop your comment as an answer, it's the good one.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Feel free to write an answer. This question will probably be closed as a duplicate anyhow.

Comment: @Dev-iL Yes, indeed, well flagged.

Comment: From what I understand, diag only works for square matrices, which is not the case here. That's why I posted a separate question.

Comment: @mythx21 - I did not mean this one and only command (since it can only be used to access values), but a solution that is based on it, such as what you can see in the linked question. [One interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15450926/3372061) avoids `diag` completely if you so desire.